# Codeigniter add_column not working as expected

Tags: php, codeigniter, dbforge

I'm trying to add some extra columns to an existing table with the codeigniter dbforge way.
I'm doing everything like this here. [dbforge,add_column](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/forge.html#modifying_tables).
It wasn't working with the migrations, but after i tried to put the exact same code into some of my controllers with profiler turned on.
After this, i saw this info on the queries part. (Attaching an image)
[image: executed code]
I saw something like that in the buglist, but there it is fixed. So after this i tried to download a git version from codeigniter, but there is the exact same problem.

The code i'm trying to run is this:

```
$fields = array(
                    'preferences' => array('type' => 'TEXT')
);
$this->dbforge->add_column('users', $fields);
```

I'm sure that is something with the file at `system/database/DB_forge.php` file, but i wasn't able to resolve it.
Could someone point me in the good direction? Is something i'm doing wrong? Is something missing?
Thanks in advance for your kind help of all.

Comment: Are you _sure_ the [migration controller and files](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/migration.html) are executed correctly? Try run an `echo` inside the migration file and see if it outputs. If an mysql error would occur, you would most likely notice this unless disabled.

Comment: the problem is not with the migrations, the copied code which you see, is not working too, it is outputing that query which you see on the image